# Usage of ElementRef in Attribute Directive?

Tags: angular

I was wondering.. Is it considered bad practice to use ElementRef in an attribute directive? Currently I am positioning some elements based on a Date variable (a timetable), and in the future want to be able to drag and drop the elements, and send the new date and time information to a database (based on the position). I found that I could do this using a Directive. But then I looked at the [documentation for ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) which states:

> USE WITH CAUTION
>
> Use this API as the last resort when direct access to
>   DOM is needed. Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular
>   instead. Alternatively you take a look at Renderer which provides API
>   that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is
>   not supported.
>
> Relying on direct DOM access creates tight coupling
>   between your application and rendering layers which will make it
>   impossible to separate the two and deploy your application into a web
>   worker.

So my question is would you consider the movement of my elements as "last resort"? If not, how would you alternate the position of an element depending on these kinds of variables?

Comment: *Last resort* is when you're unable to achieve what you're trying to do in another way, and you're sure it's not because you're doing something wrong. This doc entry also explains that the suggested way is to use Renderer (it's Renderer2 at this moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I think they tried to maximise confusion with this documentation.

Using `ElementRef` is perfectly fine.
What the docs actually refer to, is accessing methods or fields of `ElementRef.nativeElement`.

Angular goes great lengths to abstract the DOM and allow you to avoid direct DOM access to not have a strong dependency to the browsers DOM.
This allows to run Angular on the server for Server Side Rendering or in WebWorkers to spread the load over multiple CPU cores.

If you want to use SSR or Web Workers, just stay away from direct DOM access as far as possible.

If you don't intend to use SSR or Web Workers, direct DOM access is fine, especially if your are using non-Angular libraries that access the DOM directly anyway.

Comment: I guess SSR is primary reason why this warning is there. You never know when you need SSR, and direct DOM access is always a show-stopper there.

Comment: SSR is the most prominent. Isn't Ionic also depending on this DOM abstraction? I haven't tried it myself yet.

Comment: I don't use Ionic myself too, but I'd expect that it would, but I'm not sure if it's a big deal there since it relies on web view any way. But a big deal for NativeScript.

Comment: Ok, can't even tell these apart :D

Comment: Great! A little googling told me that SSR is mostly used for SEO. As this is for an intranet web page I don't think this is necessary. But concerning WebWorkers, I might want to use those. Does this mean that WebWorkers will simply not work in the app or is it only the elements who are affected by this directive which will not be able to utilise it?

Comment: I haven't done much with Angular and Web Workers. It is possible to combine Web Workers with direct DOM access, but it might need cumbersome custom code. I think it's more than a year that I checked. I'm only talking here about automatic utilization of WebWorkers by Angular, not some custom Web Worker that you yourself invoke to do some background task.